# How to keep the customer custom attribute filled in case of validation error Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, register

I have created an attribute in customer level from admin and when i submit the form and after validation, if any error occurs then it redirects to same form page with an error but the field is not pre-filled like first name and last name in register page.